# Multiplicity of zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Can you explain me how to get the multiplicity of a zero? 
In particular, I would ask you how to determine the zeros' multiplicity of

$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}z)$$

I suppose they are $z = 2k+1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and are simple zeros for the function.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f(z) = f '(z) = 0$, $f ''(z)\ne0$ , then $z$ is a double zero.

If $f(z) = f '(z) = f ''(z) = 0$, $f '''(z)\ne0$ , then $z$ is a triple zero.

And so on.

Simple zeros are characterized with $f '(z) \ne0$.

This is the case in your example.

Answer (score 3):

It suffices to show that the zero at $z=1$ is simple, i.e. that

$$\frac{\cos(\pi/2 z)}{z-1}$$ is a non-zero constant when $z\rightarrow 1$.

To do that, we use [L'Hospital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to compute the limit to be $-\pi/2 \sin(\pi/2)=-\pi/2\not=0$.

For the other zeros this works the same way.

In general, an analytic function $f$ has a zero of multiplicity $k$ at $z_0$ if there exists an analytic function $g$ defined in some neighbourhood of $z_0$ with $g(z_0)\not=0$ such that

$$f(z)=(z-z_0)^k g(z)$$

close to $z_0$. In our example, the above quotient is that function $g$ and the calculation we did was to check that $g(z_0)\not=0$.

Answer (score 2):

To find the multiplicity of a zero of $f$ calculate the logarithmic derivative $\frac{f'}{f}$ at the point.  Try it for $z^n$ at $0$!

Answer (score 0):

The multiplicity of a zero $z$ of a function $f$ is the number $n$ such that 
$$\lim_{x\to z}\frac{f(x)}{(x-z)^n}\quad\text{is finite},$$
providing that the limit exists.
(By "finite", I mean not zero and not infinite.)
Of course it is not always defined.

In your case, since (with $z=2k+1$)
$$\cos\left(\frac\pi2x\right)\underset{x\to z}\sim\cos\left(\frac\pi2z\right)+(x-z)
\sin\left(\frac\pi2z\right)+O\left((x-z)^2\right)$$
by Taylor expansion, and that $\sin((2k+1)\pi/2)=(-1)^k\neq0$, one can conclude that these zeros are simple.