# Can anyone provide a proof for this limit?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

When working through some exercises regarding limits, I stumbled across this one that puzzles me.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + x^3\right)^{\frac{1}{x-\sin(x)}} = e^6$$

Can anyone show me how you could work this out? I found the answer using wolframalpha. I know that x equals sin(x) as x tends to zero, so you raise a little bit more than one to an infinitely large power. I also know that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e.$$

But why does e pop up in the first equation? When x is raised to any other power than three the limit as x tends to zero is just one. What is it that makes three the special case?

Comment: Hint: $e^{\ln(x)} = x$ and $e^x$ is a continuous function. Also: downvotes are because your problem is isolated. Show what you have tried (or edit with the hint provided :) )

Comment: Take logarithms and use Taylor series. Compute the limit of the logarithm and exponentiate the result

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think it’s fine now @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: As both "Student" and "Claude" have tried to say in the comments, a first step is to change the problem to one you are familiar with (Clause suggests using logarithms)

i.e. we have that $$\lim_{x\to0}(1+x^3)^{\frac{1}{x-\sin(x)}}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\log(1+x^3)\cdot\frac{1}{x-\sin(x)}}=e^{\displaystyle\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{x-\sin(x)}\right)}$$

Now we only have to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x^3)}{x-\sin(x)}$ with one of the methods you have learned (l'Hopital/Taylor series/...).

The limit you mentioned $\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac1x)^x=e\right)$ seems to be a red herring.

> When x is raised to any other power than three the limit as x tends to zero is just one. What is it that makes three the special case?

This is because $\log(1+x^k)$ has a zero of order k in $x=0$ (And similarly $x-\sin x$ has a zero of order 3) (See also [this question about order of zeroes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648618/multiplicity-of-zeros)), and thus for $k>3$ we have that $\log(1+x^k)$ has a zero of higher degree than $x-\sin x$. However, for $k<3$ we would have a problem, as the limit diverges.

Comment: Why can you interchange the limit and the exponential? Or is $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} g(x))$ generally possible?

Comment: Because of continuity: A function $f$ is continuous in $a$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a)$.

Comment: Since $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\log\left(1+x^3\right)}{x^3}=1\;,\;$ you just need to calculate the limit $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^3}{x-\sin x}\;$ which is $\,6\,$ because $\;\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\mathrm o\!\left(x^3\right).$

Comment: @student91, you are right, but what you wrote is correct if $a$ is an accumulation point of the domain of the function, otherwise if $a$ is a isolated point of the domain of the function, it is not possible to calculate the limit because it does not make sense, nevertheless the function $f(x)$ is still continuous at $x=a$.